# Get current latitude and longitude in the string

Tags: android, gps, android-location

I am trying to get `latitude` and `longitude` but sometime `network is available` but I am not getting value of `latitude` and `longitude`. I am using **MyLocationListener** class and put condition all but some time `value` is not getting.

```
protected void showCurrentLocation() 
{
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

    if (location != null) 
    {
        counter++;          
        latitude=location.getLatitude();
        longitude=location.getLongitude();
        altitude=location.getAltitude();
    }
 }   

private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener
{
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
    {
         counter++;
         latitude=location.getLatitude();
         longitude=location.getLongitude();
         altitude=location.getAltitude();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle b) 
    {
    }
    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String s) 
    {   
    }
    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String s) 
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: what you want actually ?

Comment: Where are you calling the class MyLocationListener?

Answer (score 5):

Here Best way to get Longitude Latitude:

```
/** PROCESS for Get Longitude and Latitude **/
locationManager     = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

// Define a listener that responds to location updates

LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // Called when a new location is found by the network location provider.

        longitude = String.valueOf(location.getLongitude());
        latitude = String.valueOf(location.getLatitude());
        Log.d("msg", "changed Loc : "+longitude + ":"+latitude);
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
};

// getting GPS status
isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

// check if GPS enabled     
if(isGPSEnabled){

    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

    if(location != null)
    {
        longitude = String.valueOf(location.getLongitude());
        latitude = String.valueOf(location.getLatitude());
        Log.d("msg", "Loc : "+longitude + ":"+latitude);

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
    }else
    {
        /*
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
        criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
        String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
         */

        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if(location != null)
        {
            longitude = String.valueOf(location.getLongitude());
            latitude = String.valueOf(location.getLatitude());

            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
        }else
        {
            longitude   = "0.00";
            latitude    = "0.00";
        }
    }
}
```

if device is not able to get currentLocation using `GPS` then it'll be take fron `NetworkProvider` or else it'll take 0,0 as my requirement but you can modify as per your requirement

May it'll helpful to you.

Happy Coding :D

Comment: Hi Pratik, Some devices not getting current lat and long. I'm using `LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER` and `LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER`

Answer (score 0):

See, this is a very common problem. In order to have exact Latitude and Longitude ,You must use GPS also it must me activated on the mobile device but GPS too have some limitations. GPS works most efficiently under open sky. you will not have a clear range inside a building. So try your code under open sky and check the response.