# Cannot get current location until connected to the internet - Android GPS

Tags: android, gps, location

my question title is kind of self explanatory.
When I want to get my current location, for the first time(after phone start up), I have to be connected to the internet.
After getting the location once, my app no longer needs the internet connection and the update happens just fine.
At first I thought there was something missing in my code, but I tried the in-build maps application, and it also couldn't get my location until I enabled data transfer.

This seems really strange to me, if I can get coordinates without net connectivity after the first coordinate is aquired, why do I need it in the first place?

So I was wondering 2 things,
1 - is there a work around to let me get my first Location without being connected
and
2 - if there is no work around is it practical to ask the user to enable it? I'm not 100% on this but I'm pretty sure I cant enable data programatically.

Would like to hear your opinions. 
Thanks :)

Comment: How do you plan on getting the location of your device if you're not connected to the internet?

Comment: Check My Answer Here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19175359/1318946

Comment: Either WiFi or GPS has to be enabled in order to obtain current location. You can ask user to enable his GPS with simple AlertDialog and lead him to settings screen with startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));

Comment: @kjurkovic - My GPS is enabled

Comment: @Razgriz 
It works after I get my first coordinate, then I can rely purely on the GPS sensor
But for the first time update I need to have an internet connection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android devices use what's called aGPS - the a stands for assisted. The most basic I've seen it explained is that certain information has to be downloaded and a general, broad location identified in order to allow the GPS sensor to know where to look for the satellites. Once it has the information, it can find the GPS satellites, and is fine. There is no way for your app to get around that fact, I'm afraid.

Comment: Thank you very much, thats exactly what I wanted to know,
in your opinion, what is the best way for me to go about this, should I take the user to the settings page, or just let him know that data needs to be on, or do nothing like the standard maps app?

Comment: I don't believe that. AGps is only for faster first fix. GPS works without Internet. It then needs 45s insteaf of 15s. So are you sure that an android will never get an position if you never have internet BUT GPS IS ENBLED?. GPS was built for working evrywhere especially where no other orientationis possible like in deserts or woods. and there you will not have Internet access. I think he simpley has not enabled GPS (for that app)

Comment: Without the assisted data, it takes 12.5 minutes to get the information from the satellites (gps satellites transmit the data at 50 bits (not kilo or mega) per second. Moreover, if that signal with the satellite is interrupted (which could be as simple as being blocked by a tall building - it doesn't take much), it throws everything out and starts over. So if you're not in the city and out in the open, best case is that 12.5 minutes to get the first lock. Considering the mobility and typical usage area of a smart phone, that is pretty much saying it doesn't work without data

Comment: reference for the 12.5 minutes is on wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assisted_GPS#Basic_concepts

Answer (score 0):

Have you defined `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` in `AndroidManifest.xml`

If yes then check you internet connection:

Or

Check My Answer Here: [Get current latitude and longtitude](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19175359/1318946)

Comment: I have very similar code, the only difference is that I dont fall back to NETWORK_PROVIDER if GPS doesnt get my location, do you think that would help?
I dont want to use Network though, I need higher accuracy, so this can only work if it gets the first coordinate from network, and then uses GPS.
Btw, for the network provider do you need a data connection? Cause in that case it would just defeat the purpose...

Comment: Yes you need data connection, and if you want to higher accuracy then you have to go with `GPS_PROVIDER`

Comment: Yes, thats my question, how do I go directly to using GPS provider without having a data connection