# GPS location never changes

Tags: android, gps

I'm writting an app, that every 10 seconds get my coordinates and send to server.
I have a service that every 10 seconds(realized with AlarmManager) get current GPS coordinates.
But it always show only first get coordinats, why?

```
public class GpsService extends Service implements LocationListener {
// flag for GPS status
boolean isGPSEnabled = false;


// flag for GPS status
boolean canGetLocation = false;

// Declaring a Location Manager
private LocationManager locationManager;

Location location; // location
double latitude; // latitude
double longitude; // longitude

// The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 5; // 10 meters

// The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 10 * 1; // 1 minute

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Log.i("myLogs", "onCreate");
    super.onCreate();
}
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    Log.i("myLogs", "onBind");
    return null;
}
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.i("myLogs", "onStartCommand");
    getLocation();
    if(location != null) {
        Log.i("myLogs", "lat = " + Double.toString(location.getLatitude()) + "lng = " + Double.toString(location.getLongitude()));
    }
    else
        Log.i("myLogs", "no location for your today");
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.i("myLogs", "onDestroy");
    super.onDestroy();
}
public Location getLocation() {
    try {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) this
                .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // getting GPS status
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        if (!isGPSEnabled) {
            stopSelf();
        } else {
            this.canGetLocation = true;
            // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
            if (isGPSEnabled) {
                if (location == null) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("myLogs", "GPS Enabled");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return location;
}
```

}

Comment: Did you override the methods of LocationListener like onLocationChanged.

Comment: No, what i need to do in it?

Comment: Have a look at this blog post http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/06/deep-dive-into-location.html  It gives a detailed explanation about refreshing location

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19175359/1318946

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if this code gets executed for the first time, `location` is `null`
so it will assign the latest location

on the second pass, it's not null, so it skips this whole portion and never updates `location` or `latitude` or `longitude`

```
if (location == null) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("myLogs", "GPS Enabled");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: How to get new location?

Comment: remove the `if (location == null)` check.
I'm not sure if this will get you into trouble with calling `locationManager.requestLocationUpdates()` though, so you might have to find another way to make sure that *that* function is only called once.

Answer (score 0):

To make sure you get the latest and accurate location, you need to implement the location listener methods. You should also register a broadcast reciever to listen for changes in location. [Here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/06/deep-dive-into-location.html) is a blogpost that explains all this in detail. It listens for location changes and update location based on accuracy and freshness.