# Getting latitude and longitude in Android

Tags: android, geolocation, android-location

I'm trying to learn how to get the current coordinates of an Android device and I have the following code:

```
package com.example.pruebageolocalizacion;

import java.util.List;

import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        LocationManager locManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);


        List<String> listaProviders = locManager.getAllProviders();

        for(int i=0;i<listaProviders.size();i++) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),listaProviders.get(i).toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }


        if (!locManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "GPS DESACTIVADO",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else {

            Location ultimaLocalizacion = locManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            if(ultimaLocalizacion!=null) {
                    double ultimaLatitud = ultimaLocalizacion.getLatitude();
                    double ultimaLongitud = ultimaLocalizacion.getLongitude();          
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ultma latitud: " + ultimaLatitud ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ultma longitud: " + ultimaLongitud ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();             
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ultma localizacion es null",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                LocationListener locListener = new LocationListener() {
                    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ultma latitud: " + String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()) ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ultma longitud: " + String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()) ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Precision: " + String.valueOf(location.getAccuracy()) ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();              
                    }

                    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "GPS DESACTIVADO",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }

                    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "GPS ACTIVADO",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Status del proveedor" + status,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                };      

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "A",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 3000, 0, locListener);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "B",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

I have tried it both in an Android virtual device and in my cell phone and these are the messages I can see on the screen:

> "network", "passive", "gps", "Ultma localizacion es null", "A", "B",

I have enabled WIFI and GPS in both devices. And I have used the GPS of my cell phone many times. So, shouldn't  ultimaLocalizacion be different from null?

Also, if ultimaLocalizacion is null, why doesn't it show me the latitude, longitude and accuracy every three seconds?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you installed google paly services?http://velmuruganandroidcoding.blogspot.in/2013/08/how-to-get-current-latitude-and.html#.UujyW_u6Zkg

Comment: Yes, I have installed it and I have the following permissions in AndroidManifest.xml:    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />  
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

Comment: I have created code for that is : http://stackoverflow.com/a/19175359/1318946

Comment: The code works correctly as it is. It just needed to go outdoors. Sorry to bother you.