# Network location not working

Tags: android, android-location

I'm having a strange issue with getting the network location in my app. Every once and a while (wasn't find out exactly when yet), when trying to obtain location through my app the network location stops working (I manage to get only the GPS location). The only thing that solves this is restarting the phone (not even force-closing my app). Note that I've encountered this bug testing on different phones, means it's not a issue with a certain phone. Any suggestions ?

```
01-29 16:17:04.792: D/Starling.LocationHandler(1431): starting to listen to location
01-29 16:17:04.802: V/GmsNetworkLocationProvi(988): onSetRequest: ProviderRequestUnbundled, reportLocation is true and interval is 0
01-29 16:17:04.802: V/GmsNetworkLocationProvi(988): SET-REQUEST
01-29 16:17:04.802: V/GmsNetworkLocationProvi(988): in Handler: ProviderRequestUnbundled, reportLocation is true and interval is 0
01-29 16:17:04.802: D/Starling.HomeActivity(1431): after startLocationListener
01-29 16:17:04.842: V/SearchControllerCache(4077): disposing SearchController
01-29 16:17:04.862: D/dalvikvm(4077): threadid=42: thread exiting, not yet detached (count=0)
01-29 16:17:04.862: D/dalvikvm(4077): threadid=32: thread exiting, not yet detached (count=0)
01-29 16:17:04.862: D/dalvikvm(4077): threadid=49: thread exiting, not yet detached (count=0)
01-29 16:17:30.380: I/dalvikvm(1417): Jit: resizing JitTable from 4096 to 8192
01-29 16:17:30.770: D/Starling.LocationHandler(1431): location change gps
01-29 16:17:30.820: D/Starling.LocationHandler(1431): turning off location listener
01-29 16:17:30.820: V/GmsNetworkLocationProvi(988): onSetRequest: ProviderRequestUnbundled, reportLocation is true and interval is 86400000
01-29 16:17:30.820: V/GmsNetworkLocationProvi(988): SET-REQUEST
01-29 16:17:30.820: V/GmsNetworkLocationProvi(988): in Handler: ProviderRequestUnbundled, reportLocation is true and interval is 86400000
```

As you can see I didn't get the location from the network...

```
public void startLocationListener(LocationListenerManager manager){

        this.manager = manager;
        Log.d(TAG, "starting to listen to location");
        mlocManager =  (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        gpsEnabled = mlocManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);



        mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
        mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);

private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener{
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location newLocation) {

            Log.d(TAG, "location change " + newLocation.getProvider());

                    location = newLocation;

                location.getLongitude() + " " + location.getLatitude() );
                Log.d(TAG,"onLocationChanged "+newLocation.getLatitude()+" "+newLocation.getLongitude());
                manager.onLocationChanged(newLocation);
                endLocationListener();


        }
```

Comment: Put a log cat then it is easy to analyze and getting better response from others

Comment: @PratikButani I've added some logcat, that I think is relevant

Comment: @SIVAKUMAR.J I've added some logcat, that I think is relevant

Comment: What does endLocationListener() do? Also I didn't see the code where you log "after startLocationListener". I think the problem is that you are ending the listener when first location is received. So, if your gps is getting location faster than network, you'll never get a location from network.

Comment: I do end it after getting the first. But how can the GPS return faster than the network if it wasn't on before? furthermore, If I don't listen to the GPS at all I just don't get the location.

Comment: See this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/19175359/1318946