# Can't get location from Android

Tags: android, android-location

I'm trying to get the location of my device, but have only been successful one time out of running the code several times. Below is the code I'm using:

```
    final LocationListener mLocationListener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            Log.d(TAG, location.getLatitude() + ", " + location.getLongitude());
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {
            Log.d(TAG, "changed: " + s);
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {
            Log.d(TAG, "enabled: " + s);
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
            Log.d(TAG, "disabled: " + s);
        }
    };

    LocationManager mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(getActivity().getApplicationContext().LOCATION_SERVICE);

    boolean enabled = mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    Log.d(TAG, "gps enabled?" + enabled);
    Log.d(TAG, "network enabled?" +  mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER));

    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    best = mLocationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

    Log.d(TAG, best);
    Log.d(TAG, LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    Log.d(TAG, LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

    mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(best, 0, 0, mLocationListener);
```

I am indoors (I would like this to work indoors), so I keep getting the `best` to be `network`. Both the `gps enabled` and `network enabled` strings are printing out `true`. Is the reason that I am inconsistently getting a location, or is there something I can do to fix this so I can get a location indoors?

Comment: You should use the Fused provider (https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19175359/1318946

Comment: If you are preferring to use it indoors why bother using GPS? And either way, the request is being made only with any one provider so I don't see much chance for the inconsistency.

Comment: @SoothSayer I am now using the Fused provider as you suggested, and it's working great. If you want, you could post your comment as an answer, or I'll delete the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So for device location, using the Fused provider allows to get far better results.

In addition, you will not need to manage different providers.

[Android developer documentation about location](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html)